# How to print directories containing two files matching two different patterns?

Tags: bash, unix, find

I want to write a bash script that (among other things) find Makefiles where Makefile is in the same directory as python files, (files that look like *.py).

I can do it rather inelegantly in several steps by doing two separate finds and comparing output, but I thought there might be a way to do a one line find command?  It just seems like there should be a way?

so

```
path1/Makefile
path1/Some.py
path2/Makefile
path3/Makefile
path3/path4/Makefile
path3/path4/Another.py
```

path1 will be printed.

path2 will not.

path3 will not be printed.  b/c python files need to be at the same level.

path3/path4 will be printed.

So the general question is, can I use find to find directories containing at least two files, one matching one pattern, the other matching another pattern, but both patterns must be met by separate files?

thanks.

btw, I am using
    find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2.

But, I'm just interested in what people come up with as answers.  I've done the inelegant solution, but it be nice to see.  It's always helpful and educational.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do this with find conditions alone, but of course you can always use `-exec` to construct something like this:

```
find . -name '*.py' -exec bash -c 'test -f $(dirname "$1")/Makefile' -- {} \; -print
```

This prints the list of *.py files which have a Makefile in the same directory.  If you strip off everything after the final forward slash, you get just the directories containing those files, for example by piping through `sed 's:/[^/]*$::'`.

This solution has the advantage of only running a single `find`, at the cost of spawning a shell for each and every `.py` file found.  Note that `test` is a builtin in most shells.

---

You could alternately do this in bash alone, bypassing `find` altogether:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/./*.py; do
  test "${file%/*}/Makefile" && echo "${file%/*}"
done | uniq
```

The "globstar" option allows `**/*.py` to search through subdirectories, as `find` does, and with this solution we can use parameter expansion in lieu of a subshell that runs `dirname`.  The output is, as you asked for, the list of directories containing files that match your criteria. The output is filtered through `uniq` in case multiple `*.py` matches exist in a single directory.

**Update per Etan's comment:**

Note that in order to accommodate the possibility of the *current* (topmost) directory containing *.py and a Makefile, the glob is `**/./*.py` instead of `**/*.py`.  The result causes every matched path to end with a dot.  While this will still find all the target directories (`/foo/bar/.` is the same as `/foo/bar`), if it bothers you, you can strip the trailing dot path segment by adding `| sed 's:/\.::'` after `uniq`.  Adding such a filter would make the output appear the same way as `dirname`-based solutions.

Comment: If your `find` has `-exec \+` that might be of use as you could loop the arguments in the inline script and test each one individually then do the printing directly from there (and skip `-print`).

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  Works fine in FreeBSD, but I'll leave this answer as-is since I don't know the background of `-exec ... +`.

Comment: Added an untested version of my suggested modification to my answer.

Comment: Isn't this the same as `find . -name '*.py' -exec test -f $(dirname {})/Makefile \; -print` ?

Comment: @JeffY - no, it's not. If `$(..)` is expanded by your shell as the find command command line is being evaluated, it isn't being expanded for each instance of `'*.py'` found by the first condition. You need to run the `dirname` inside a subshell for this to work, because `$(..)` is shell syntax, not an option to `/bin/test`.  The `-exec` option searches `$PATH` for a command to run, it doesn't know about builtins in the calling shell.

Comment: The `dirname` avoidance will fail to find the current directory (if the current directory has both a python file and a Makefile) because it will not replace `barename.py` with `.`. Though that probably doesn't matter for this scenario.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I've updated the answer to handle that condition.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want just the immediate common parent directory printed out and not the matching file names as well then I think this will work. (Though I feel like there have to be nicer ways to do this.)

Note: Requires `GNU find` for `-printf`.

```
find "$topdir" -name '*.py' -printf '%h\0' | xargs -0 -I {} find {} -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name Makefile -printf '%h\n' | sort -u
```

For a non-`GNU find` option (modified from [ghoti's handiwork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33109220/258523) (untested):

```
find . -name '*.py' -exec sh -c 'for file; do d=$(dirname "$file"); test -f "$d"/Makefile && printf "%s\n" "$d"; done' -- {} \+
```

`-exec ;` runs the command once for each matching file. `-exec +` assembles a single command line with as many files as will fit in a single command so runs **many** fewer instances of the shell for large lists of matching files.

Comment: My `find` doesn't have a `-printf` option.  Are you using the same OS as the poster?

Comment: @ghoti He doesn't specify so I don't know. I didn't realize `-printf` was a GNU option though (though I probably should have).

Comment: Tried the last edit, doesn't appear to work, seems to list the same directory over and over again.

Comment: @Bitdiot Sorry, forgot to change `$1` to `$file`. Try it again?

Comment: Tried it.  Works!  Fantastic.  Love the solutions.  I'd like to give a checkmark to every right answer here.  I'll give it to the most popular?  I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Bitdiot Fine, just realize they have different requirements and different performance characteristics. The `-exec ;` version is almost certainly going to be the slowest. The two `find` versions here are likely similar and I don't have a sense of how the bash-only one performs but probably fairly well. Though the memory usage of these options likely differs also (only noticable at very large amounts of files probably).

Answer (score 2):

Try this with bash:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for i in **/Makefile; do i="${i%/*}"; x=( "$i"/*.py ); [[ -n ${x[0]} ]] && echo "$i"; done
```

Output:

```
path1
path3/path4
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this `find` in a `while read` loop using *process substitution*:

```
shopt -s nullglob

while IFS= read -rd '' dir; do
   ary=("$dir"/*.py)
   [[ -f "$dir"/Makefile && ${#ary[@]} -gt 0 ]] && echo "$dir"
done < <(find . -type d -print0)
```

`find` command will find all the directories from current directory and inside the `while` loop we're checking for existence of `*.py` files and `Makefile` in each of those directories.

Comment: Why would you suggest this?  How is this solution an improvement over the bash solutions from ghoti and Cyrus?

Comment: Because 1. It avoids forking a sub-shell for each python file in sub-directories. 2. Will work with older bash versions (<4) as well since `globstar` was introduced in BASH 4

Answer (score -1):

`find` has a `-o` flag to combine multiple patterns. Like this:

```
find \( [pattern for path1] -o [pattern for path2] \)
```

Comment: That'll find files which match *either* predicate but not directories that have files that match *both*.

Comment: @EtanReisner Ah I see. Sorry, I completely misunderstood your question.